# Firebase.push failed: first argument contains an invalid key($$typeof)

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, firebase, react-native

I am learning react native for the first time for developing android app not IOS one and I was learning from **Building a Simple ToDo App With React Native and Firebase** tutorial from youtube.But I am getting an error while trying to add items. I get following error

**Firebase.push failed: first argument contains an invalid key($$typeof) in property 'restaurant.restaurant_name.targetInst._nativeParent._currentElement'.keys must be non-empty strings and cant contain ".","#","$","/","["**

What might be creating this issue?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import Firebase from 'firebase';

import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TouchableHighlight,
  TextInput,
  ListView
} from 'react-native';

class foodOrderSystem extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    const firebaseRef = new Firebase('foodordersystem.firebaseio.com');
    console.log(firebaseRef);
    this.itemRef = firebaseRef.child('restaurant');
    this.state = {
        newRestaurant:'',
        // estimated_delivery:'',
        // description:'',
        restaurantSource: new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (row1,row2) => row1 !== row2})
    };
    this.restaurant = [ ];
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.itemRef.on('child_added', (snap) => {
        this.restaurant.push({
            id:snap.key(),
            text:snap.val()
        });
        this.setState({
            restaurantSource:this.state.restaurantSource.cloneWithRows(this.restaurant)
        });
    });

    this.itemRef.on('child_removed', (snap) => {
        this.restaurant = this.restaurant.filter((x) => x.id !== snap.key());
        this.setState({
            restaurantSource:this.state.restaurantSource.cloneWithRows(this.restaurant)
        });
    });

  }

  addRestaurant(){
    if(this.state.newRestaurant !== ''){
        this.itemRef.push({
            restaurant_name: this.state.newRestaurant
        });
        this.setState({ newRestaurant:''});
    }
  }

  removeRestaurant(rowData){
    this.itemRef.child(rowData.id).remove();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.appContainer}>
        <View style={styles.titleView}>
            <Text style={styles.titleText}>
              foodOrderSystem
            </Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.inputcontainer}>
            <TextInput 
                style={styles.input} 
                onChange={(text) => this.setState({newRestaurant:text})}
                value={this.state.newRestaurant} />
                <TouchableHighlight
                    style={styles.button}
                    onPress={ () => this.addRestaurant() }
                    underlayColor="#00ffff">
                    <Text style={styles.btnText}>Add</Text>
                </TouchableHighlight>
        </View>
        <ListView
            dataSource={this.state.restaurantSource}
            renderRow={this.renderRow.bind(this)} />
      </View>
    );
  }

  renderRow(rowData){
    return(
        <TouchableHighlight
            underlayColor="#dddddd"
            onPress={() => this.removeRestaurant(rowData)}>
            <View>
                <View style={styles.row}>
                    <Text style={styles.todoText}>{rowData.text}</Text>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.separator} />
            </View>
        </TouchableHighlight>
    );
}
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  appContainer:{
    flex: 1
  },
  titleView:{
    backgroundColor: '#48afdb',
    paddingTop: 30,
    paddingBottom: 10,
    flexDirection: 'row'
  },
  titleText:{
    color: '#fff',
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    flex: 1,
    fontSize: 20,
  },
  inputcontainer: {
    marginTop: 5,
    padding: 10,
    flexDirection: 'row'
  },
  button: {
    height: 36,
    flex: 2,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    backgroundColor: '#48afdb',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    color: '#FFFFFF',
    borderRadius: 4,
  },
  btnText: {
    fontSize: 18,
    color: '#fff',
    marginTop: 6,
  },
  input: {
    height: 36,
    padding: 4,
    marginRight: 5,
    flex: 4,
    fontSize: 18,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: '#48afdb',
    borderRadius: 4,
    color: '#48BBEC'
  },
  row: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    padding: 12,
    height: 44
  },
  separator: {
    height: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#CCCCCC',
  },
  todoText: {
    flex: 1,
  },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('foodOrderSystem', () => foodOrderSystem);
```

Here is the attachment of error

[image]

Comment: Hi @pri! Is all of this code necessary to reproduce the problem? This looks like you just posted your entire app and asked us to debug. Can you reduce this to the relevant code? See [creating an mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Kato i have reduced the code. Problem is in .push().

Comment: And does the key contain $$typeof?

Comment: Hey.. I have tried your code... I havent got the error you are getting. Its working for me. But after updating to firebase I got an error in line 'restaurantSource:this.state.restaurantSource.cloneWithRows(this.restaurant)'

Comment: have you got any solution?

Comment: Nope. It is still not working on mine.

Comment: I have used https://firebase.google.com/

Comment: Hey.. Share your complete component class source code ,including styles etc.. I will try to debug the issue

Comment: Hey! I'm struggling with the same issue, but with ReactJS. Did you find a solution for this? Thanks!